# Como activar un botón con respecto si se ha agregado texto en un JTextField

Tags: java, validación, jtextfield, jbutton

Busco que se active un botón con respecto a si se introdujo texto en un campo de texto, para después realizar una acción con el botón.

Es decir, que el botón inicie desactivado, y cuando se ingrese texto en un JTextField se valide que hay texto y esto active el botón.

Un ejemplo es:

```
 txtNombre = new JTextField();
 txtNombre.setBounds(175, 50, 100, 25);
 btnActivar = new JButton("Activar");
 btnActivar.setBounds(175, 150, 100, 25); //este es el boton que quiero que se active cuando se ingrese texto
 btnActivar.setEnabled(false);// es decir una condición para que esto cambie de false a true y viceversa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `addDocumentListener()` para monitorear los cambios y activar/desactivar el boton cuando haya contenido.

```
txtNombre = new JTextField();
btnActivar = new JButton("Activar");
txtNombre.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    updated();
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    updated();
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    updated();
  }

  public void updated() {
     btnActivar.setEnabled(textField.getText().length()>0);
  }
});
txtNombre.setBounds(175, 50, 100, 25);
btnActivar.setBounds(175, 150, 100, 25); 
btnActivar.setEnabled(false);
```